# Able to create user without providing security credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to create a new IAM user in my account.As you can see in the code, I have not provided any kinds of security credentials in my code but still a new user is created in my account. How is the code able to link it to my account without the credentials?. I have no credentials file stored anywhere on my computer.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Create the IAM service object
var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});
var username= process.argv[2];

var params = {
   UserName: username
};

iam.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err && err.code === 'NoSuchEntity') {
     iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
         throw err;
      } else {
         console.log("Success", data);
      }
    });
  } else {
        console.log("User " + process.argv[2] + " already exists", 
        data.User.UserId);
    }
});
```

Comment: You certainly followed something like [step 3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html).

Comment: I deleted my credentials file already

Comment: Did you check environment variables ?

Comment: nothing there too. Is it possible that it is automatically logging in to my account using iam.aws.amazon.com or something similar?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) are the ways to provide credentials. Certainly one of those is your case, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: You are right. I will check again. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Does this code runs in a EC2 instance which is assuming a role with IAM privileges?